# NGINX Redirect Bad Gateway Only When a Subdirectory Is Provided

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've installed nginx on ubuntu 20.04 and set it up to do redirects. This is my conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.185:6052;
    }

    location /esphome {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.185:6502;
    }
```

}

If I enter http://10.0.0.185 in a browser, it redirects me to the site.

If I enter http://10.0.0.185/esphome in a browser, it gives me a 502 error.

I've also tried just having the second location as the only one and still get the same error

I've tried adding ending slashes to the urls. It has no effect.

I've also tried other websites on the same server. When I tried /adguard to 10.0.0.185:8080, I got a forbidden response. When I tried /frigate to 10.0.0.185:5000, it just hung.

When I changed the entry to:

```
        location /esphome {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Port $server_port;
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.185:6052;
    }
```

I get a 404 error. Strangely when I comment out the set header values, I still get the 404 error instead of the original 502.

Are there additional parameters that I have to add to the second location?

I have a small flock of web servers on the ubuntu image so I'd like to map to each one thus the need for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try different matching types, e.g. `^~`, `=` and so on to see if it matches your use case.

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.185:6052;
    }

    location ^~ /esphome {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.185:6502;
    }
```

You can find out more here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

Comment: Thanks for the link. There's lots of useful information there. The /esphome doesn't work when it's the only entry.